# (Laravel) Join 3 or more tables using "Eloquent Relationships"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, laravel, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables using eloquent relationships, but it doesn't give the expected results.

Shipment model

```
class Shipment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ccctadm.Shipment';

    public function customergroupcode()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentRuleSet::class,'customergroupcode','customergroupcode');
    }
    public function shipmentcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentRuleSet::class,'shipmentcategory','shipmentcategory');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentRuleSet::class,'status','status');
    } 
}
```

to get the data i'm using this code

```
   $shipment_data = Shipment::With(['customergroupcode' , 'shipmentcategory','status'])->
Where('shipment_cycle','!=','closed')->get();
```

I'm trying to make it  equivalent to this query

> ```
>  select B.rulesetname,B.icon ,COUNT(*)As Total  from
> [ccct].[ccctadm]. [Shipment] A  INNER  JOIN 
> [ccct].[ccctadm].[documentruleset] B
>      ON
>       A.customergroupcode = B.customergroupcode  AND A.shipmentcategory =  
>    B.shipmentcategory AND A.status = B.status INNER
> JOIN [ccctadm].[shipassign] S ON  A.id = S.shipmentid AND
>  A.shipment_cycle != 'closed'  GROUP BY  rulesetname,B.icon
> ```

The first query  returns all the data in 3 tables, but when the second one returns Release only and this what I want

I only want the data that has relation among these three tables not everything

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method. It limits the records based on existence of the relationship.

```
$shipment_data = Shipment::has('customergroupcode' , 'shipmentcategory','status')->
Where('shipment_cycle','!=','closed')->get();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'shipmentcategory' to data type int......    I think has  works for int  values only, while shipmentcategory is not!

Comment: @Ahmadz No. has() method is related to relationship existence. and the error is may be due to [ ]. i've updated the answer.

Comment: I tried to remove the array, but still same error. all columns type are Nchar

Comment: @AhmadzIssa are you sure `with()` method worked properly?

Comment: The error  because of count(*)  in subQuery---Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'shipmentcategory' to data type int. (SQL: select * from [ccctadm].[Shipment] where (select count(*) from [ccctadm].[documentruleset] where [ccctadm].[Shipment].[customergroupcode] = [ccctadm].[documentruleset].[customergroupcode]) = shipmentcategory and [shipment_cycle] != closed)

Comment: are you sure both the shipmentcategory(PK) and shipmentcategory(FK) are nvarchar?

Comment: Yeah and I tried to convert them to varchar ,but didn't work.  The problem because of the SubQuery it returns integer due "count() func"  and  then comparing it with a string    "shipmentcategory column"   than  it produce an error